# How to set a PHP Session once at start

Tags: php, session

I have a problem with my current PHP/MySQL application.

I am using a 3rd party piece of software that generates PHP Code and with it I am using a 'Dropbox' style addon, this works great in principal but the problem I am having is that the original code assumes that the user will be logging in using the standard login form that comes with the software.  This is affecting me because there is an events page that allows you to add custom events per page; in this case the event placed in "after successful logon" is being bypassed because I am logging in using SSO through Joomla and displaying as an iframe.

As a result the code that is getting bypassed is `$_SESSION["current_folder"]`, which is used to filter a list of files/folders that the user sees to set their root folder.  This then gets overwritten later on when creating subfolders et (each folder has an `id`, and `parent_id`, etc, and the session for parent id is given by the `$_SESSION["current_folder"]`.

So initially the `$_SESSION["current_folder"]` must be 0, then gets updated as the user browses.

The problem I have is the only other place I can add code is on the global events page (which runs each time any page is loaded) so whilst this gets me in to view the file list, if I use `$_SESSION["current_folder"] = 0` it has unfortunate effect of placing every sub folder created at the root folder as it overwrites the correct session to 0.

On the global events page I have added `include_once('docsetting.php')` which basically is `$_SESSION["current_folder"] = 0`, but this isn't working either.

Is there a way to set the `$_SESSION["current_folder"] = 0` at startup using a global event, something similar to `run_once` that I have missed?

Comment: never mind, got it working with if ($_SESSION["current_folder"])
 $_SESSION["current_folder"] = $_SESSION["current_folder"]; 
 else $_SESSION["current_folder"]=0;

Comment: That may well work, but it's completely wrong to do something like that. I'd recommend something like this: `if(!isset($_SESSION['current_folder']) || empty($_SESSION['current_folder'])) $_SESSION['current_folder'] = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

```
   if ($_SESSION["current_folder"]) $_SESSION["current_folder"] =
   $_SESSION["current_folder"]; else $_SESSION["current_folder"]=0;
```